# Generate any number in the fewest step using multiply by 2 or divide by 3?

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

Generate any number in the fewest step using multiply by 2 or divide by 3? Any idea how to solve this problem efficiently? I am thinking about dynamic programming but not sure.
So for example, the best solution I can think of to get 7 is through 2*2*2*2*2*2/3/3 = 7. I mean integer division in C++ or Java here. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify the goal is to generate any natural number.

Comment: But no natural number (other than pure powers of 2) are powers of 2 divided by powers of 3. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: What does "divide by 3" mean? Mathematical division, giving fractional numbers, or truncating integer division like the "/" operator in languages like C or Java? And what's the number that you start with? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: A simple example might clear things up. How would you reach `7`?

Comment: Sorry guys. So the starting point is 1. You would get 7 by 2*2*2*2*2*2/3/3 = 7. I am doing integer division so basically you can do round down in the case of 7. Thanks!

Comment: It isn't completely clear that all natural numbers can be so expressed, but if they can be then a dynamic programming approach is certainly a natural way to determining how to do so as efficiently as possible.

Comment: i guess you mean integer division? hmm...

Comment: @JohnColeman Can you elaborate on the recurrence relation for DP approach? Thanks!

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr By division I am referring to the '/' operator used in C++. Thanks!

Comment: I would think of it as a BFS from 1.

Comment: So basically, for each element in the BFS queue, you do multiply by 2 and divide by 3 and push it back to the queue until you encounter the number you want? For example if 3 is at the front of the queue, you multiply it by 2 and get 6, divide by 3 and get 1. You then push that two new number to the end of queue? @JohnColeman

Comment: Something like that, although I would think of it as a tree rather than a queue. There might be a better way, though this way will work. The tree could become quite large.

Comment: it has to be large. this looks finding solutions for collatz conjecture, but a bit weaker. i won't expect polynomial time solution.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Thanks for pointing that out. I will definitely look into the collatz conjecture problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnColeman: 2^p/3^q can be brought as close as you want from any number, so all naturals can certainly be expressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a BFS dynamic programming solution.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
wanted = 7
found = {1: None}
added = [1]
while True:
    new_added = []
    for x in added:
        if 2*x not in found:
            found[2*x] = [x, 2]
            new_added.append(2*x)
        if x/3 not in found:
            found[x/3] = [x, 3]
            new_added.append(x/3)
    if wanted in found:
        break
    # This magic line copies new_added over the added array.
    added[:] = new_added

answer = []
path = [wanted]
while path[-1] != 1:
    node = found[path[-1]]
    path.append(node[0])
    answer.append(node[1])

print([x for x in reversed(answer)])
print([x for x in reversed(path)])
```

Here is an explanation.

BFS means Breadth-First Search.  In this case we are searching in parallel through all paths of lengths 1, 2, 3, etc until we are done.

Dynamic Programming refers to any of a variety of methods to store a record of work done so that we can either avoid work, or refer back to already done work.

In this case `found` is a record of all numbers that we have found a path to with the integer you get there from, and what operation to use.  `added` is the record of all integers that we found on the last pass.  `new_added` is all of the integers that we found on this pass.

So we start with a record saying that we know how to get to `1`.  Then in each pass we take all of the just added records and see what new ones we get to by multiplying by 2 or dividing by 3.

We stop once we found our target.  And then it is a question of finding the path back through `found` to get back to 1.  This gives us our answer but in reverse order - the end of the path is at the start of our list.  So reverse it and we have our answer.

Which I displayed both as a record of all of the numbers we visit and as a record of the operations.

Comment: it would have been nice if you had some explanation also to go with this code.

Comment: @nomanpouigt I added a short essay explaining it.  The challenge is that you don't know what you can and can't assume about the reader.  The less you assume, the more you need to explain, which makes the explanation longer and therefore less likely to be read.

Answer (score 0):

**--- EDIT: DOES NOT FIND THE SHORTEST SOLUTION ---**

*After describing the following algorithm, I was told that it does not find the shortest solution.*

My idea is to start from our number N, repetitively multiply by 3 (considering the uncertainty range that integer division by 3 introduces for the product), and check if a power of two lies witin the current uncertainty range.

E.g. for N=7:

- Range0 = 7...7, no power of 2 in range
- Range1 = 21...23, no power of 2 in range
- Range2 = 63...71, a power of 2, being 2^6 = 64, lies within the range, so the solution is 2^6 / 3^2 = 7.

I'm not sure that every natural number N can be reached that way. So the algorithm might not terminate.

And I feel the intermediate numbers can get quite large even for small N values, so a BigInteger implementation will probably be necessary.

If N = 2^a / 3^b, then the algorithm will run in O(a+b).

Java program with 64-bit integers:

```
package test;

public class TwoThreePower {

    static void printPowers(int n) {
        int exp3 = 0;
        long rangeMin = n;
        long rangeMax = n;
        int exp2 = 0;
        long power2 = 1;
        while(true) {
            if (power2 < rangeMin) {
                power2 = power2 * 2;
                exp2 = exp2 + 1;
            } else if (power2 <= rangeMax) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%d is 2^%d / 3^%d", n, exp2, exp3));
                return;
            } else {
                rangeMin = rangeMin * 3;
                rangeMax = rangeMax * 3 + 2;
                exp3 = exp3 + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
            printPowers(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This already fails at n=40, so I created (less readable) BigInteger version:

```
package test;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigTwoThreePower {

    public static final BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    public static final BigInteger THREE = BigInteger.valueOf(3);

    static void printPowers(int n) {
        int exp3 = 0;
        BigInteger rangeMin = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
        BigInteger rangeMax = rangeMin;
        int exp2 = 0;
        BigInteger power2 = BigInteger.ONE;
        while(true) {
            if (power2.compareTo(rangeMin) < 0) {
                power2 = power2.multiply(TWO);
                exp2 = exp2 + 1;
            } else if (power2.compareTo(rangeMax) <= 0) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%d is 2^%d / 3^%d", n, exp2, exp3));
                return;
            } else {
                rangeMin = rangeMin.multiply(THREE);
                rangeMax = rangeMax.multiply(THREE).add(TWO);
                exp3 = exp3 + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
            printPowers(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the results for N=1 to 99:

```
1 is 2^0 / 3^0
2 is 2^1 / 3^0
3 is 2^5 / 3^2
4 is 2^2 / 3^0
5 is 2^4 / 3^1
6 is 2^9 / 3^4
7 is 2^6 / 3^2
8 is 2^3 / 3^0
9 is 2^8 / 3^3
10 is 2^5 / 3^1
11 is 2^13 / 3^6
12 is 2^10 / 3^4
13 is 2^18 / 3^9
14 is 2^7 / 3^2
15 is 2^23 / 3^12
16 is 2^4 / 3^0
17 is 2^20 / 3^10
18 is 2^9 / 3^3
19 is 2^17 / 3^8
20 is 2^44 / 3^25
21 is 2^6 / 3^1
22 is 2^14 / 3^6
23 is 2^22 / 3^11
24 is 2^30 / 3^16
25 is 2^11 / 3^4
26 is 2^19 / 3^9
27 is 2^46 / 3^26
28 is 2^8 / 3^2
29 is 2^16 / 3^7
30 is 2^62 / 3^36
31 is 2^24 / 3^12
32 is 2^5 / 3^0
33 is 2^13 / 3^5
34 is 2^59 / 3^34
35 is 2^21 / 3^10
36 is 2^48 / 3^27
37 is 2^10 / 3^3
38 is 2^56 / 3^32
39 is 2^18 / 3^8
40 is 2^64 / 3^37
41 is 2^45 / 3^25
42 is 2^7 / 3^1
43 is 2^53 / 3^30
44 is 2^15 / 3^6
45 is 2^80 / 3^47
46 is 2^42 / 3^23
47 is 2^23 / 3^11
48 is 2^69 / 3^40
49 is 2^31 / 3^16
50 is 2^12 / 3^4
51 is 2^58 / 3^33
52 is 2^39 / 3^21
53 is 2^20 / 3^9
54 is 2^66 / 3^38
55 is 2^47 / 3^26
56 is 2^9 / 3^2
57 is 2^74 / 3^43
58 is 2^55 / 3^31
59 is 2^17 / 3^7
60 is 2^82 / 3^48
61 is 2^63 / 3^36
62 is 2^44 / 3^24
63 is 2^25 / 3^12
64 is 2^6 / 3^0
65 is 2^52 / 3^29
66 is 2^33 / 3^17
67 is 2^14 / 3^5
68 is 2^79 / 3^46
69 is 2^60 / 3^34
70 is 2^41 / 3^22
71 is 2^22 / 3^10
72 is 2^68 / 3^39
73 is 2^49 / 3^27
74 is 2^30 / 3^15
75 is 2^11 / 3^3
76 is 2^76 / 3^44
77 is 2^57 / 3^32
78 is 2^38 / 3^20
79 is 2^19 / 3^8
80 is 2^84 / 3^49
81 is 2^65 / 3^37
82 is 2^130 / 3^78
83 is 2^46 / 3^25
84 is 2^27 / 3^13
85 is 2^8 / 3^1
86 is 2^73 / 3^42
87 is 2^54 / 3^30
88 is 2^35 / 3^18
89 is 2^16 / 3^6
90 is 2^81 / 3^47
91 is 2^146 / 3^88
92 is 2^62 / 3^35
93 is 2^43 / 3^23
94 is 2^24 / 3^11
95 is 2^89 / 3^52
96 is 2^154 / 3^93
97 is 2^70 / 3^40
98 is 2^51 / 3^28
99 is 2^32 / 3^16
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that is doesn't *generate the number in the fewest steps.* For example, your method uses 247 steps to reach the number 96. But 96 can be reached in 12 steps: `96=2*2*2*2*2/3*2/3*2*2*2*2`

Comment: @user3386109 I have to think about why the order of steps makes such a difference.